# LINQ to SQL visualizer for VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, visualizer

I am trying to find a LINQ to SQL visualizer for Visual Studio 2010.

Anybody know of one somewhere?

When i was using vs 2008 i used this [one](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx).

But with vs 2010 it does not work.

I tried this [one](http://www.rajavenkatesh.com/projects.aspx), but it didn't work either!

Is there a visual studio 2010 visualizer for Linq to SQL ?? thanks

The tools must be integrated in vs 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After research i found this [article](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2010/06/08/vs-2010-and-expression-tree-visualization/) and they talk we need to recompile the linq-to-sql visualizer with vs 2010 dll reference, and it's working very nicely.

So there is the solutions

> Moreover while this meta language can express things more concisely, I guess they’ll be a range of scenarios where I’ll prefer to keep using [C# 2008 Samples Expression Tree Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397975%28VS.90%29.aspx) (Expression Tree visualization through a Windows Form Tree) or [Manuel Abadia Linq Expression Debugger Visualizer](http://www.manuelabadia.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,9160035f-490f-46bd-ab55-516b5c7545af.aspx) (Expression tree visualization through a graph). I noticed that both these addin doesn’t work as-is on VS 2010 and the trick I wanted to share here is that, to use them under VS 2010, you just need to recompile them by referencing the VS 2010 assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll (found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll) instead of the VS 2008 assembly with the same name. This works like a charm with the C# 2008 Samples Expression Tree Visualize used in VS 2010 on .NET 4 and .NET 3.5 projects. I expect the same good result with the Manuel Abadia piece of code (but source code is not available here so I couldn’t recompile, Manuel can you do that?).

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [LINQpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)?

Comment: I dont think this will work .. :-( LINQPad supports SQL Express, SQL 2000, SQL 2005, and (with some limitations) SQL 2008. I am not sure they have a visualizer tools for VS

Comment: @Cedric Brown - LinqPad fully supports SQL 2008. And I am pretty sure LinqPad will allow you to do everything the 'visualizer' in your link will do.

Comment: Sorry, i talk about SQL ... I make a mistake, it's was about visual studio they say "If you have Visual Studio 2008 or Visual C# 2008 Express"

Comment: LINQPad doesn't integrate with Visual Studio, it's a standalone application, so you can use it without having to have VS installed at all; just a supported .NET Framework version.  Although the tool is free, be aware that you don't get autocompletion without purchasing a license.  I can tell you that purchasing a license is money well-spent. LINQPad is a must-have tool, and I think it pretty much killed that 2008 visualizer project.

Comment: I need a integrated vs 2010 tool.