# How do I get the Linq to SQL Debug Visualizer working with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql, linq

It can be found at:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx

I tried opening the project and recompiling the dll using latest references and .NET4.0 but I can't get it running.  There's not too much code in it so it can't be that difficult (for a real .NET pro!)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759995/linq-to-sql-visualizer-for-vs-2010